# Find the next "interesting" time

Tags: code-golf, date

I happened to glance at my watch today at exactly 11:11:11 (and today is 1/11; too bad it's not 2011), and that got me thinking: *I know! I should make a code golf question out of this! <sub>I'm a dork.</sub>*

Anyway, your challenge is to take an hour, minute, and second as input, and output the next "interesting" time. Here, I will define interesting as these steps:

1. Concatenate the hour, minute, and second. (For example, at 4:14:14, this would be 41414.)
2. Check for consecutive groups of one, two, or three that span the length of the entire string. For example, I could find `[41][41][4]` in the example time (if the group cannot reach through the string, just cut it off like I did in this example). Another example: in the time in my first example at the beginning of the question, it would be `[1][1][1][1][1][1]`, `[11][11][11]`, or `[111][111]`.
3. Is there a consecutive group that goes all the way through the string? If so, the time is "interesting!" Otherwise, it's not.

The input can be in any *reasonable* format, but it must not be hardcoded. The output can also be in any *reasonable* format, and it need not be in the same format as the input.

If you use network access for some reason, **all** bytes downloaded from the network count to your score.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: It's January, not November :P

Comment: @Volatility Whoops, typo :-P fixed

Comment: I like the network access restriction.

Comment: Should code only consider times on a 12 hour clock? For example, on a 24 hour clock 14:14:14 would be an interesting time but not so interesting on a 12 hour clock (2:14:14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### J, <s>113</s> <s>99</s> 90

Probably still quite golfable.

```
f=:t#:[:(>:^:([:(3&g+:2&g=.[:*/]=(]$)${.)@(":@{.,3}.7":100#.1,])t#:])^:_)1+(t=.24,2$60)#.]
```

Takes a vector `(h m s)` as input, and returns a vector in the same format as output.

Examples:

```
   f 0 0 0
0 1 0
   f 4 14 14
4 14 41
   f 23 59 59
0 0 0
   f 3 14 15
3 14 31
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - <del>227</del>223

That's one way of doing it.

```
    import Data.List
e _ []=False
e f s=let (h,t)=f s in t`isPrefixOf`h||h`isPrefixOf`t&&e f t
i [a,b,s]=head[t|s<-[s+1..],f<-map splitAt[1..3],let m=b+s`div`60;h=a+m`div`60;t=[h`mod`24,m`mod`60,s`mod`60],e f$concatMap show t]
```

Examples

```
λ: i [11,11,11]
[11,21,1]
λ: i [4,14,14]
[4,14,41]
```

Comment: Could you post a sample run? I'm clueless about Haskell so I have no idea how the input/output works, etc :-P

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 125

```
F=Do[#~MatchQ~{#〚-1〛..,_}&&Break@#&@Partition[(i=IntegerDigits)@f[n~i~60,100],m,m,1,a_],
{n,#~(f=FromDigits)~60+1,7^6},{m,3}]&
```

It returns a pattern of the next interesting time:

```
F@{11, 11, 11}
F@{4, 14, 14}
```

> {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}
>
> {{4, 1, 4}, {4, 1, a_}}

`a_` marks the end of the time.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua

I've got four different solutions, as I wasn't sure about some of the requirements.

**Version 1: removal of 0s, command line input as well as os.time() backup (315)**

Minimised:

```
z=arg if z[1] then y={hour=z[1],min=z[2],sec=z[3],day=1,month=1,year=1}end h,g,e,u=os.date,os.time(y),":",tonumber while 1 do g=g+1 b,c,d=u(h("%H",g)),u(h("%M",g)),u(h("%S",g)) a=b..c..d for x=1,#a/2 do p=1 for _ in a:gmatch(a:sub(1,x))do p=p+1 if p>math.ceil(#a/x) then print(b..e..c..e..d)return 1 end end end end
```

Full version with comments:

```
z=arg if z[1] then y={hour=z[1],min=z[2],sec=z[3],day=1,month=1,year=1}end --get command line arguments
h,g,e,u=os.date,os.time(y),":",tonumber --set up references, if command line arguments accepted use y else use current time
while 1 do
    g=g+1
    b,c,d=u(h("%H",g)),u(h("%M",g)),u(h("%S",g)) --get HH:MM:SS seperately (which allows removal of the zeroes with tonumber())
    a=b..c..d  --concat
    for x=1,#a/2 do  --check up to half of the string
        p=1
        for _ in a:gmatch(a:sub(1,x))do --for each match
            p=p+1  --count number of matches
            if p>math.ceil(#a/x) then print(b..e..c..e..d)return 1 end --if matches span entire string, cheer (and print in a pretty format)
        end
    end
end
```

The other versions are very similar, so I will only post the minimised versions:

**Version 2: no command line input (239)**

```
h,g,e,u=os.date,os.time(),":",tonumber while 1 do g=g+1 b,c,d=u(h("%H",g)),u(h("%M",g)),u(h("%S",g)) a=b..c..d for x=1,#a/2 do p=1 for _ in a:gmatch(a:sub(1,x))do p=p+1 if p>math.ceil(#a/x) then print(b..e..c..e..d)return 1 end end end end
```

**Version 3: no 0 removal, with command line input (240)**

```
z=arg if z[1] then y={hour=z[1],min=z[2],sec=z[3],day=1,month=1,year=1}end h,g=os.date,os.time(y) while 1 do g=g+1 a=h("%H%M%S",g) for x=1,3 do p=1 for _ in a:gmatch(a:sub(1,x))do p=p+1 if p>6/x then print(h("%T",g))return 1 end end end end
```

**Version 4: none of the fancy stuff (no 0 removal or command line input) (164)**

```
h,g=os.date,os.time() while 1 do g=g+1 a=h("%H%M%S",g) for x=1,3 do p=1 for _ in a:gmatch(a:sub(1,x))do p=p+1 if p>6/x then print(h("%T",g))return 1 end end end end
```

**Usage instructions**

In a terminal, run (versions 1 and 3)

```
lua interesting.lua HOURS MINUTES SECONDS
```

or just

```
lua interesting.lua
```

If you want it to go off the system clock.

Is there a prize for feature completeness? :P